# Django swap not null fields - getting IntegrityError due to unique_together

Tags: python, django, atomic, integrity

My model holds a not null ForeignKey to another model, which is also part of the unique_together.

```
class MyModel:
    ...
    a_link = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel, null=False)
    ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ((a_link, ))
```

Now I want to swap `a_link` between instances of MyModel `a` and `b`. (In reality a few more than two).

I get an `IntegrityError` with Duplicate entry, which is perhaps not so strange but even `atomic()` doesn't change anything to the better:

```
with atomic():
    for obj, to_ in a_list.items():
        obj.type = to_
        obj.save()
```

Even setting them outside and just looping the `save()`within the `atomic()` doesn't help.

Am I stuck with creating an algo that puts the objects in the correct order, use a tmp variable for one of them, loop the list and then set the last one?

Comment: What database are you using? If it supports deferrable constraints (as PostgreSQL does) then you can defer the uniqueness check until the transaction is committed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL doesn't have deferred constraint checking.